# How can I get more digits for a p-value?

Tags: regression, stata

Does someone know an easy way to get Stata to display more than just three digits for the p-value when running a Tobit regression?

Normally Stata reports that the p-value is `.001` or `.065`, but I would like to see more digits, for example, `.0011123` or `.065320`.

To be clear, I don't want to (necessarily) alter the way the data is produced in the regression table.

I only want to be able to get Stata to display more digits for those p-values I am interested in.

Comment: Do you *really need* more than 3 digits? I would guess most people would report p-values to 2 digits for which an output of 3 digits is more than enough. Could you clarify *why* you need more digits?

Comment: Bonferroni corrections with large models (hundreds of variables) is one reason.

Comment: @whuber That is a very good point.

Comment: @suncoolsu I suspect Gunter's comment was made in a different context, probably one where someone was trying to overinterpret something like a p-value of 10^-100 or thereabouts.  The fact is that interpreting and using moderately low p-values (10^-4 to 10^-6) is a significant issue: it has been the subject of national regulations and of federal litigation in the US, for instance, so it's not something to be dismissed with a flippant comment.  I thank you for making clear that you offer the quotation at least partially in jest!

Comment: @whuber .. My sincere apologies, the comment was fully in jest. I removed it cuz it doesn't belong to a serious discussion like this. I actually didn't know that p-value that low is a big issue in US. Thanks for letting me know. I wonder what do they gain gain from trusting p-value that low apart from gaining the knowledge "something is wrong".

Comment: @suncoolsu It shows up in regulations governing the monitoring of the environment.  Monitoring programs can result in conducting tens of thousands of tests simultaneously, creating a need to avoid false positive results.

Comment: @whuber Thanks you very much ! .. I really value the knowledge that I gain from this forum!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow up the tobit command with

`est tab, p(%12.10g)`

(for example).  This ought to work even in pretty old versions of Stata.  A little less easy is to write your own output procedure.

Comment: Good idea. I'd add that -est tab- is an abbreviation (understood by Stata) for the built-in command -estimates table-. That was introduced with the release of Stata 8.0 in 2003.

Answer (score 5):

[Stata 11.1 introduced](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?whatsnew) a `set pformat` command that specifies the output format of p-values in coefficient tables. (I don't know about [STATA](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/res/statalist.html#spell) I'm afraid as I think that was discontinued some time in the 1980s).

By the way, you'd probably be better off asking such completely Stata-specific questions on [Statalist](http://www.stata.com/statalist/) rather than here.

Comment: To avoid the need to lookup formats -  `set pformat %5.4f, perm` will increase the displayed value in the output table from 3 to 4 decimal places

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times, you can get the utmost precision if you know your p-value by its internal name. I usually type `return list` or `ereturn list` after nearly every command that I will seriously use, and then grab results that may look like `e(p)` or `r(p)` or `e(p_chi2)` or whatever the scalar that contains the p-value might be.

Comment: Whenever possible, I do this too. However, p-values are not always "left behind" after estimation commands (`ereturn list`). A nice way to get the p-values from those commands is described here (http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0137) and uses some basic `mata` functions. However, the `set pformat` and `set tab` solutions are much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

After a tobit regression, you can use the `test` command to get the p-value from the null hypothesis x1=0:

```
sysuse auto
tobit weight trunk length headroom, ll(1500)
test trunk
```

The result returned in `r(p)`

```
return list
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the first example from the `tobit` command help file:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
. generate wgt = weight / 1000

. tobit mpg wgt, ll(17)

Tobit regression                                Number of obs     =         74
                                                LR chi2(1)        =      72.85
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -164.25438                     Pseudo R2         =     0.1815

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         wgt |   -6.87305   .7002559    -9.82   0.000    -8.268658   -5.477442
       _cons |   41.49856    2.05838    20.16   0.000     37.39621     45.6009
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      /sigma |   3.845701   .3663309                      3.115605    4.575797
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            18  left-censored observations at mpg <= 17
            56     uncensored observations
             0 right-censored observations
```

You can easily obtain any p-value from the returned results in `r()`:

```
. matrix list r(table)

r(table)[9,3]
             model:      model:      sigma:
               wgt       _cons       _cons
     b  -6.8730504   41.498557   3.8457011
    se   .70025591   2.0583803   .36633085
     t  -9.8150552   20.160782          .b
pvalue   5.610e-15   1.471e-31          .b
    ll  -8.2686584   37.396211   3.1156048
    ul  -5.4774424   45.600903   4.5757975
    df          73          73          73
  crit   1.9929971   1.9929971   1.9929971
 eform           0           0           0
```

And then format it accordingly:

```
. matrix results = r(table)

. display %18.17f results[4,1]
0.00000000000000561
```

Type `help format` from Stata's command prompt for more information.